# Android layout: Quadratic views

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-layout

In an Android application I need to add a view to my RelativeLayout that obeys the following rules:

1. The view should be quadratic, i.e. the height and the width of the view must match.
2. The view should fill the whole WIDTH.

It should look like this (the square should be centered vertically):

```
+-------------+
|  activity   |
|             |
|+-----------+|
||           ||
||  square   ||
||           ||
||           ||
|+-----------+|
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

In the end I want to have an ImageView that displays a quadratic image. Currently I did this by setting both width and height of the view to FILL_PARENT, and let the ImageView draw the image correctly (using scaleType=centerInside).

But: Now I want to have an additional view that is aligned with the top line of the square view, and this is where my approach fails.
If I now set the width of the view to FILL_PARENT and the height of it to WRAP_CONTENT, the image will not fit the whole width any longer.

Do you have a solution to this problem? It would be preferrable if this could be done by just writing XML, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the top answer on this question.

[Android layout with square buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948212/android-layout-with-sqare-buttons)

Comment: Ok, so it does not seem to be possible just by using XML, but creating a custom layout. I used the SquareLayout described there, simplified the onMeasure method and it works perfectly. Still I think a solution just based on the current layout managers should have been better, but unfortunately it seems that some use cases like mine are not supported... Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure that coding the layout in Java is the only way. But at least now you have SquareLayout defined, you can re-use it in your XML as many times as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two views to be beside each other then neither one can have FILL_PARENT. Sounds like what you need is a horizontal LinearLayout containing the ImageView and the other view. Then set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` on the ImageView, that will make the ImageView fill the parent. Then set the layout_width of the other View to "wrap_content".

```
<LinearLayout android:width="FILL_PARENT" android:height="WRAP_CONTENT">
   <ImageView android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
   <OtherView android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT" android:layout_width="WRAP_CONTENT" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, this does not work. In your case the ImageView will wrap to the size of the image - which should be scaled upwards. Besides, I can align the views in my RelativeLayout quite well - I just need the ImageView to have the correct size (width = height = width of activity).

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension of LinearLayout that does exactly what you want. I've wrapped the thing in an Android Library project for convenience.
See https://github.com/ronaldsteen/Android-SquareLayout-Library