# How do i set cell height to be as it's width in android TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have TableLayout as following:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow>
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/b1"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center" />
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/b2"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center" />
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/b3"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center" />
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Each Button has the same width. 
I want the height of those buttons to be exactly the same as their width.
I tried to do it programmally by:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setHeight(b1.getWidth());
```

but it doesn't work (it gave me value of 0). I suppose it because when i do it (inside onCreate method) the button isn't set yet.

Comment: This is a similar questions that may give you a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948212/android-layout-with-sqare-buttons

Answer (score 1):

First, you are right, you get value of 0, because the screen didn't draw yet when you try to get the button `width`.

As I see it, the only possibility to do it like you want, is to give them pre defind value in the XML file.

For example:

```
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/b1"
     android:layout_width="25dip"
     android:layout_height="25dip"
     android:gravity="center" />
```

Set the width and height programmally:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

btnWidth = metrics.heightPixels/3 - 50;//gap
btnHeight = btnWidth;

Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setHeight(btnWidth);
b1.setWidth(btnWidth);
```

Comment: the problem is that i want 3 squares that will be all over the width of the screen

Comment: @LiorZ You are right, if you use this method you can't use `android:layout_weight`. So way you don't give all the button equal width from the beginning? You can do it in the xml file, or when you create the screen, get your device width, divide it with 3, and add a little gap between them, then set it programmally.

Comment: i don't know the width from the beginning because i want the buttons to be in equal width and will be all over the width of the screen and i can do it only with xml. 
I tried to do it programmally by dividing the screen to 3, and layout the buttons with this value, but the method layout uses integers and the width of the buttons can be double, therefore it creates ugly gaps. But when i using xml it solves the problem.

Comment: i prefer to do it without gaps.

Comment: the real problem is that i already tried to do it programmally, but i want to set a drawable background for the button. but when i do it i can't set gravity for the button. that why i tried to do it in xml...

Comment: @LiorZ Did you try to use `imagebutton` instead?