# layout button corresponts to background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

In Android Studio, I want the size of the buttons as well as the distance between them to change with the size of the display.

Basically, I have a background with special places for buttons (I know it's a bad practice) and on different screens, the buttons don't fit the background.

I've tried to accomplish this via `ConstraintLayout`, but `match_constraint` makes the size of the button large as the container and `margins` are static.

I've tried [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3147157/7429499), but it didn't work properly.

[image: simple schema as example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to do this in `ConstraintLayout` either. A chain with percentage guidelines will need its children to be set to `wrap_content`. Therefore the size of the buttons will remain the same, for example in landscape and portrait modes. Therefore I used "empty" `View`s in a LinearLayout. By giving each element, the buttons AND the empty views, a weight, you can achieve the effect of button sizes relative to screen width. Voila:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1666" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1666" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".1666" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]